# Septic tank depth sensor

Tags: ultrasound

I am on a hunt for a depth sensor for my septic tank.

The task: to measure the current depth of a septic tank, where I would submerge the device where the sensor would send a ping to detect the distance to the bottom.

I was looking at different types of sensors, for example with infrared using ToF. The issue is the substance has different densities.

How should I approach this problem?
Would a ultrasound sensor be the direction? What kind of wave length should be so it overcomes the density of the fluid and pings back from the actual plastic and or concrete floor?

Constraints: Nothing can be attached to the lid, the device will be looking from the surface level down

Comment: Consider a radar: https://www.sensorsone.com/radar-liquid-level-sensors/#:~:text=A%20radar%20liquid%20level%20sensor,it%20to%20an%20electrical%20signal.&text=Radar%20liquid%20level%20sensors%20are,of%20a%20liquid%20based%20substance.  Radar has the advantage that it can "see through" plastics so if your tank is suitable, you can mount the sensor outside the tank. But if you have to ask what it costs then you probably cannot afford it.

Comment: If you measure the distance from the top of the tank to the surface, you can subtract that from the height of the tank to get the depth it's filled to. Then there is no need to submerge the device.

Comment: It's not clear to me what exactly you're trying to measure. Do you want to measure the depth/height of the tank itself (from lid to floor), or do you want to measure the depth to which the tank is currently filled, or both? If you're wanting to measure depth of fill, then why? For a septic tank, any condition other than 'full' is an unusual/abnormal state and should only occur if the tank has recently been pumped or is damaged & leaking.

Comment: I added 2 constraints, maybe polish septic tanks are different, they slowly fill up, after a certain level they need to be emptied

Comment: My septic tank has a water level that is essentially constant, and equal to the height of the outlet to the drain field. However, the level of **solids** in the bottom of the tank increases over time. Does your septic tank not have a drain field?